# Multiple ASIFormDataRequest response handle in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest framework for using server side request and response. I don’t want use request and response method each view controller class. I want to use  a separate singleton class for service handling function,then that class fires service success and failure properly. I implemented this idea in my ios project.

But multiple request done by at a time,then I can’t get proper response for which I requested one. Please go through my following code.In this code I am using a  custom delegate in my `service handle` class. I think when multiple request done by at a time, this custom delegate method  may be changed.

Note: At a time multiple request from different view controllers.

**ServiceHandle.h**

```
@protocol serviceDelegate <NSObject>

     -(void)successFullResponse:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req;
     -(void)failedResponse:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req;
@end

@interface ServiceHandle : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property (nonatomic,weak)id<serviceDelegate>delegate;

+ (id)sharedInstance;
-(void)loginWithUserName:(NSString *)userName;
-(void)userReg:(NSDictionary*)userDict;

@end
```

**ServiceHandle.m**

```
 static ServiceHandle *sharedInstance = nil;

 @implementation ServiceHandle
 @synthesize delegate,queue;

+(ServiceHandle *)sharedInstance{

if (sharedInstance == nil) {

    sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
}
return sharedInstance;
}
 - (id)init
{
   self = [super init];

   if (self) {
    // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would
}
return self;
}


-(void)loginWithUserName:(NSString *)userName{

if (![self queue]) {
    [self setQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]];
}

NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@userLogin",webserviceURL];

NSString *lattitude=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mylatitude"];
NSString *longitude=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mylongitude"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
 [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
[request setPostValue:userName forKey:@"userId"];
[request setPostValue:lattitude forKey:@"latitude"];
[request setPostValue:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestSuccess:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFail:)];
request.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh;
request.delegate = self;

[[self queue]addOperation:request];
}

-(void)requestSuccess:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

  if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successFullResponse:)]) {

    [self.delegate successFullResponse:request];
  }
}

 -(void)requestFail:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedResponse:)]) {

    [self.delegate failedResponse:request];
  }
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)clickLogin:(id)sender{

     ServiceHandle *sharedObj = [ServiceHandle sharedInstance];
     sharedObj.delegate = self;
     [sharedObj loginWithUserName:@“usrName”];
 }

-(void)successFullResponse:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req{

    NSString *responseString = [req responseString];
    NSLog(@"responseString is%@",responseString);
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"dict is :%@",responseDict);
  }
-(void)failedResponse:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req{


  }
```

Comment: Please use a newline every once in while, as well as spaces after punctuation to prevent the wall-of-text effect that scares people away from reading your question. For in-line code (fragments) use backquotes.

Comment: @Anthon,thank you for your comment.Can you help me??

Comment: Sorry no, haven't used Objective-C for ages. I was just reviewed your question as it was marked as that it could use some improvement.

Comment: Did you think about using native methods? NSURLSession lets you send a completion block with each request. You can be very specific about what object handles each response.  Als ASI for networking is very old not a good thing to use these days IMO

Comment: @Abizern,Can you suggest a good method for calling webservice in ios?Give me also good example..